# Meteor Collection schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to add a user flow for my website so that when a when user creates an account, a record is kept of their progress. The data would have to initialized with default values. In javascript obj notation I would picture it like this:

```
buyingandselling: {
        components: {
            video: {
                complete: false
            },
            exam: {
                complete: false
            },
            finish: {
                complete: false
            }
        },
        complete: false,
        next: "overheads"
    },
    overheads: {
        components: {
            video: {
                complete: false
            },
            exam: {
                complete: false
            },
            exam2: {
                complete: false
            },
            finish: {
                complete: false
            }
        },
        complete: false,
        next: "overheads"
    }
```

I am finding very hard to understand how to can translate it to a schema. This would also only be a small part over a larger schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Accounts.onCreateUser()` to automatically add this structure to the user document on creation. You'll then be able to update it as they make progress.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  user.progress = {
    { buyingandselling: {
      components: {
        video: {
          complete: false
        },
        exam: {
          complete: false
        },
        finish: {
          complete: false
        }
      },
      complete: false,
      next: "overheads"
    },
    overheads: {
      components: {
        video: {
          complete: false
        },
        exam: {
          complete: false
        },
        exam2: {
          complete: false
        },
        finish: {
          complete: false
        }
      },
      complete: false,
      next: "overheads"
    }
  };
  return user;
});
```

Your structure looks like it has one redundant level of nesting (since each item can only be complete or not) but that's a modeling style preference.

Comment: Hey thank Michel looks perfect. Thanks a million. Where is the best place to  load this script , in my lib config folder ?

Comment: `/server/something.js`